# Angular login authentication with json rest api

Tags: json, angular

I am trying to make a login authentication in angular, in which when we are entering email id and password we are getting a token. So for authentication, we have to send that header in the api get request but i am not able to do it.

My code is shown below

onSubmit(form:NgForm) {

```
this.http.post('https://pikreview.com/rest/user.php?f=authenticate',

    JSON.stringify({

        email: "a@gmail.com",
        password: "12345"
    })
).subscribe(res => {

    localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
    var authToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    console.log("token is " + authToken);
    var headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
        'token': `${authToken}`,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
    });
    var req = new HttpRequest('GET',
         'https://www.pikreview.com/rest/user.php', {
            headers: headers,
            withCredentials: true
        }
    );

    this.http.request(req).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
}, error => {
    console.log("something went wrong");
});
```

}

And one thing i have seen that whenever i pass token header there is something set-cookie generated which has token value on authentication page but on profile page it is not getting the same token and i think therefore it is showing invalid token.So,if anyone knows something about it and can solve my problem,please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: Please add any code that you might have written for the implementation

Comment: i have added the code

Comment: architecture is important. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54852173/can-someone-explain-me-how-the-interceptor-catch-error-function-with-providers/54854228#54854228

imo, use an interceptor or extended http class to handle your auth headers

Comment: i dont know whenever i am using tokeninterceptor and adding header in it then i am not able to execute my post request while get request is running smoothly and without post request i cant authenticate

Comment: you don't have to stringify the data param of `http.post()`

Comment: that stringified http.post() is working i m talking about later with which headers are sent

Answer (score 0):

You just simple call the api with ur custom header, use HttpHeaders like this:

```
        const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': "YOUR_TOKEN"
          })
        }
      this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/getUser',httpOptions)
```